# DynamoDB - deleting items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What is the best approach to delete multiple rows in table?

From [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.06) I see that to do a deletion I need pass primary key.
That would mean that I need to delete item one by one.

1. Is it possible to handle deletion of multiple items with single request? (I do not mean batch request.)
2. How are you handling GDPR right to be forgotten?

Comment: Why would using DynamoDB's batch deletes not do what you want?

Comment: I did not write batch delete would not do it. I am just searching whether there is an other way.  The way where for example I could just by single call remove a thousands or items (instead of 25 that is limit for batch). If is significant change calling a function 1000 times or  calling another one.